# unable to get current url in angular 6

Tags: angular

I am trying to get current url in angular 6 (url not parameters.) in auth.gurd the purpose of this to protect the user accessibility as per the role.

```
console.log(this.router.url);
```

I am simply doing this in `canActivate()` funtion of auth.gurd.
The problem over here is. I am getting one old url.
ex. I am at `/admin/dashboard` now then it will print `/` and if I click on `/admin/orders` then it will print `/admin/dashboard`.

I trying all other way like snapshot and other solution.

```js
constructor(
  private api: ApiHttpService,
  private router: Router,
  private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

canActivate(): boolean {
  console.log(this.router.url);
  if (this.api.loggedIn()) {
    return true;
  } else {
    this.router.navigate([''])
    return false
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want to get new url then you have to use snapshot at component level not in auth guard.Because when auth-guard gets called in url you will always find old one and after authentication you will accessible to new url so that's why you have to use snapshot at component level

Comment: If you want to authenticate as per roles than you can go as per this example.
https://ryanchenkie.com/angular-authentication-using-route-guards

Comment: share `console.log(this.router)`

Comment: @Aarsh Yes. component level will be my last option. Becasue If I do so. I need to add/implement the same code in every component.. :(

Answer (score 3):

You can get requesting url using this in authguard :

```
@Injectable()
export class HasPermissionService implements CanActivate {

   private permissions = [];

   constructor(private _core: CoreService) { 
     this.permissions = this._core.getPermission();
   } 


   canActivate(
      route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
      state: RouterStateSnapshot
    ): Observable<boolean>|Promise<boolean>|boolean {
       //check here
    }
}
```

pass ActivatedRouteSnapshot and the RouterStateSnapshot in canActivate() as arguments it will give you requesting url.

You can get more of this here : [CanActivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate)